A man who could control his inner body functions
Probably from the 1970s.  I think he went out on assignments and could control body functions like his heart rate, breathing, etc.  In one episode he stopped them all to appear to be dead.
I remember another scene where he got shot and fell in the water.  He was healing himself by cutting off blood flow and healing the tissue around the bullet wounds while trying to control himself to need less oxygen while he was underwater. The show would cut to pictures of internal organs or blood flow being controlled while he was doing these things.

This sounds like the Bionic Woman season 2 episode Biofeedback from 1977:

Jaime teams up with Darwin Jones, an expert in meditation and biofeedback to stop his brother Payton from selling a code analyzer to foreign powers. If they get their hands on the analyzer, the identities of every OSI agent are at stake.

In the episode, Darwin is able to slow down his body functions with meditation and even stop his heart, and later on manages to heal from a bullet wound underwater; all of these changes inside his body are shown on screen. The episode is currently available on Youtube.

Thanks for the reply.  The show I'm thinking of was its own show where the guy that controlled his body was the star.  I used to watch it every week though I don't know how many episodes aired.  Maybe just 1 season.

@user16309 That's quite a coincidence, then... Did you check out the episode? It's here and in 42:10 (and then 43:10) you can see him healing from his bullet wound underwater by controlling his blood and lowering his heart rate (and we can see this happening inside his body).

I watched the episode and you're right.  This is what I had remembered.  Funny how the mind twists things up years later.  I had remembered it as a show that aired every week but it was just one episode of the  bionic woman that had stuck in my mind.  Thanks for answering this for me.  It was a great pleasure to watch that again.
